# Using LINQ to sort a Class that inherits from LIST<TTYPE>

Tags: c#, linq

If I wanted to sort a a List where TType = Parameter,

```
    public class Parameter
    {
        public string VendorId { get; set; }

        public string RunMonth { get; set; }

        public string CoverageMonth1 { get; set; }
   }
```

I would do this, for example.

```
List<Models.Parameter> ps = new List<Models.Parameter>()
{
        new Models.Parameter() { EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1) }
        ,new Models.Parameter() { EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1) }
};

ps = ps.OrderBy(p => p.EffectiveDate).ToList<Models.Parameter>();
```

What if I have a class, ParameterCollection, that inherits from `List<Parameter>`

```
        public class ParameterCollection : List<Parameter>
    {
            //handy properties added
    }
```

I get this error:

```
ParameterCollection parameterCollection;    
parameterCollection = parameterCollection.OrderBy(parameter => parameter.EffectiveDate);

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Category    Suppression State
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<StateAssessment.Models.Parameter>' to 'StateAssessment.Models.ParameterCollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  StateAssessment.Services    C:\Workspace\Healthcare-Finance_IT\Main\WebApps\StateAssessment\StateAssessment.Services\Parameter.cs   32  Compiler    Active
```

Is there a way to handle the casting to ParameterCollection in the LINQ statement?

Comment: Maybe create a `ToParameterCollection(this IEnumerable<Parameter> ...` extension method?

Comment: Eric: Yes, the cast failed/

Comment: Yacoub Massad: Can you give an example of such a method?

Comment: This is essentially abusing the class construct. Instead of inheriting, just hold a property that contains the list.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a new `ParameterCollection` to hold the elements in their new order.

```
var ps2 = new ParameterCollection();
ps2.AddRange(ps.OrderBy(p => p.EffectiveDate));
ps = ps2;
```

Of course, you could make life easier for yourself by creating a constructor overload that passes into the `List<>` overload that takes an `IEnumerable<>` to start with.

```
ps = new ParameterCollection(ps.OrderBy(p => p.EffectiveDate));
```

You could even create an extension method off of `IEnumerable<Parameter>`.

```
ps = ps.OrderBy(p => p.EffectiveDate).ToParameterCollection();
```

You might also consider getting rid of `ParameterCollection` entirely, since using inheritance in this way is a bit of an antipattern.

Comment: In my code, I do not have objects that are defined as LIST<Parameter>, other than the ParametersCollection class inheriting from this type. Hence, in your example, I would not have a p2 variable of LIST<Parameter> type to sort. I'm looking for a clean, hopefully succinct way to sort the type that is available, ParametersCollection, I am weak in LINQ and sometimes get lost in generics, but expect that the best solution resides there, so I was looking for help. The answer need not include these technologies

Comment: @ChadD: If you look carefully, the `ps2` variable in my example is not of type `List<Parameter>`, so it's doing what you're asking for. I've given you four possible approaches to solving this problem. Another possible approach would be to use the `Sort()` methods that you inherit from the `List<>` class. But I would caution you not to ignore the advice you're getting here. What value are you getting from `ParameterCollection`? If you changed all your code to use `List<Parameter>` instead, what would be missing?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say that in your example the variable "ps" appeared to be of type LIST<Parameter> and you were adding it to a new ParametersCollection object. I would not have a ps  variable of List<Parameter> as my starting point.Re: "If you changed ...".: I would be missing all of the added methods that apply only to collections of LIST<PARAMETER> collections. I'm not sure why this is an anit patetrn

Comment: @ChadD: What made you think that `ps` was a `List<Parameter>`? I was assuming it was a `ParameterCollection`. RE: "I would be missing...", the fact that you say those added methods apply to collections of `Parameter`s leads me to believe that they could just as easily be extension methods on `IEnumerable<Parameter>`, `ICollection<Parameter>`, `IList<Parameter>` or some such.

Comment: @ChadD: The reason your current approach is an antipattern is explained by your question itself: you could solve your own problem with one line of code if you were using `List<Parameter>`, but because you've tied yourself to an inherited type, you're having to ask people on StackOverflow for help. If you want to research this further, look up "Inheritance vs Composition".